# adding convex hull to points plotted on a map

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, points, convex-hull

I have managed to get quite a decent map of China now in R and I have managed plot some spatial data onto it using geom_points from two separate csv files. I think there is a way of having all the points in one file and sorting them but I have not gotten that advanced yet.

I need to turn these points into a convex hull. I have tried following steps online but I just can not get it. Here is my code:

```
#import data
sus_scrofa_lp <- read.csv(fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM","C:/PhD/data/s-scrofa_lp.csv")
sus_scrofa_ho <- read.csv(fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM","C:/PhD/data/s-scrofa_ho.csv") 

#create a map of china - start
library(maptools)
china_map1 <-readOGR(dsn="C:/PhD/data/bou2_4p.shp")
#SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
class(china_map1)
length(china_map1)
china_map2 <- china_map1@data
head(china_map2)
library(ggplot2)
china_map3 <- fortify(china_map1)
head(china_map3)
china_map2$NAME <- iconv(china_map2$NAME, from = 'GBK') #the original coding format is GBK
#create a map of china - end

ggplot(china_map1, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_path(color="grey40") +
  geom_polygon(fill = 'beige') +
  geom_point(data=sus_scrofa_lp, aes(lon, lat), inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = 0.5, size = 0.5, color ="red") +
  geom_point(data=sus_scrofa_ho, aes(lon, lat), inherit.aes = FALSE, alpha = 0.5, size = 0.5, color ="blue") + coord_equal()
```

Here is what I have:[points plotted on map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4DQi.png)

here is the data for s-scrofa_ho.csv https://www.dropbox.com/s/0w6iqlky5cbipch/s-scrofa_ho.csv?dl=0

here is the data for s-scrofa_lp.csv https://www.dropbox.com/s/sr49y94rby0o1sm/s-scrofa_lp.csv?dl=0

Comment: Hi Tom. We don't have your data, so it's difficult to advise. Have you tried the function `chull`?

Comment: I have tried but unsure how to get it to plot. New to this site, should I share some data?

Comment: It's very difficult to debug without any data. Anyone on the site who tries to run your code would just get an error because the data doesn't exist on their computer. If they wanted to test or verify solutions they would need to find or recreate data they thought might be similar to yours, but even if they went to all that effort, it could easily turn out that there were important differences between their data and yours, so their solution wouldn't work for you. Everyone ends up frustrated when that happens, which is why including a link to your data is vital if you want a useful answer here.

Comment: true, I have added links to my two data sources. Will remember that in future.